# Could not open password protected zip archive

Tags: php, passwords, zip, archive, libzip

I was creating a zip archive with php 7.4 (lib-zip version 1.6.1) without any problems.

Now I try to protect these zip archive with a password. Not just for encrypting with php, but in general. I found this [tutorial](https://odan.github.io/2018/02/18/creating-encrypted-zip-files-with-password-in-php.html). It does what it should, but I could not read the files of the zip archive any more. If I doubleclick on the archive, the password prompt opens up, but it does not work with the password from the source code. I also copy and pasted it to prevent any keyboard struggle.

```
<?php

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filePath = sprintf('%s/test/', __DIR__);
$fileName = 'test.zip';
$absoluteFilePath = $filePath . $fileName;
$excludeFolderNames = [
  '.',
  '..',
  '.DS_Store',
  $fileName,
];

$zipFlag = ZipArchive::CREATE;
if (file_exists($absoluteFilePath)) {
    $zipFlag = ZipArchive::OVERWRITE;
}

$createFile = $zip->open($absoluteFilePath, $zipFlag);
if (true !== $createFile) {
    throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('could not open file in "%s" caused by %s', $fileName, $createFile));
}

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filePath));
$password = 'top-secret';
if (!$zip->setPassword($password)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Set password failed');
}

/** @var SplFileInfo $value */
foreach ($iterator as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($value->getFilename(), $excludeFolderNames)) {
        continue;
    }

    $cleanFilePath = realpath($key);
    if (!$cleanFilePath) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('could not create real path from filepath: %s', $key));
    }

    $zipName = str_replace($filePath, '', $cleanFilePath);
    if (!$zip->addFile($cleanFilePath, $zipName)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Add file failed: %s', $cleanFilePath));
    }

    if (!$zip->setEncryptionName($zipName, ZipArchive::EM_AES_256)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(sprintf('Set encryption failed: %s', $zipName));
    }
}

$zip->close();
```

Does someone has the same problem or am I the problem?

**UPDATE I:**
I tought it solves my problem to save the zip-file outside the folder I want to zip. So I changed the following line:

```
$absoluteFilePath = sprintf('%s/%s', __DIR__, $fileName);
```

After a while the error occured again.

One possible reason I discovered, were .DS_Store files. In my example I exclude them. But the error occured again.

**UPDATE II:**
One further problem is, that there is no password prompt, if all files are empty.

**UPDATE III:**
Same code works with files without line break, but the error occurs, if the file has multiple lines.

Comment: Post your code with minimal example.

Comment: Yes. I also get 'unsupported compression method 99'. It indicates no reason to me because it works, if there is only one line in the file no matter if there are special characters. But ony command line it never works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found help at the [php-bugtracker](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79634). It turns out that I can extract all the files with an [zip-extension](http://www.koozie.org/blog/2014/08/creating-aes256-encrypted-zip-archive-files-mac-command-line/#aes256-encrypted-zip-files) like the comments tryed to tell me before. Now I wait for the new [libzip](https://github.com/nih-at/libzip/pull/153) version 1.7.0, where the default zip encryption is available. After this I hope I can extract my files without any extension.